# Why won't Selenium in Python click the pop-up privacy button?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am having some issues with Selenium not clicking the pop-up privacy button on https://www.transfermarkt.com/

Here is my code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.transfermarkt.com/')
accept_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/button')
accept_button.click()
```

It comes up saying:

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/button"}

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: There is not such button when I open this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that the element you are trying to click is inside an `iframe`. In order to click that element you'll have to first switch to that frame. I noticed the iframe has `title="SP Consent Message"` so I'll use a CSS Selector to identify it based on that. Your code with the added line:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.transfermarkt.com/')
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe[title="SP Consent Message"]'))
accept_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/button')
accept_button.click()
```

Note that you may have to switch back to the default frame to continue your test, I'm not 100% sure as that iframe has gone away.

Also it seems like some folks don't get that popup when the hit the website, not sure why, may be something you want to look in to to determine how you want to test this.

Like @Prophet says you should improve the xpath for the button (again it seems to have a unique title so I would use CSS Selector `'button[title="ACCEPT ALL"]'`), but this works for me to click it.

Comment: Thanks for much for the help @C.Peck. This code works great. 

I also did not see any popups going to the website on my browser, but it exists through Selenium or using incognito. Cookies must be automatically tracked, otherwise.

Comment: @bzh cool! If the solution works for you, can you accept the answer please?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues here:

1. You need to add wait / delay before `accept_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/button')` to let the page load
2. It's very, very bad practice to use absolute XPaths. You have to define an unique, short and clear related XPath expression.

Additionally, I see no  pop-up privacy button when I open that page. So, maybe that element is indeed not there.

Comment: Waiting is not the issue... You couldn't have seen this since you don't see the popup (not sure why) but it's because the button is inside an iframe.

Comment: Well, if so.. BTW, why me and vitaliis do not see that pop-up?

Comment: location? I don't know, I couldn't say, but the asker says it always shows up when running from chromedriver.

Comment: I also saw that, OK.